# Override properties file when running jar

Tags: java, jar, properties-file

I am trying to create a .JAR from a package that I have been working on and have run into a problem. I want a user to be able to modify the properties with which the program is run.

My package's folder structure looks like this:

```
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
(...)
│   │   └───resources
│   │           dbinterface.properties
```

and I want to override the dbinterface.properties file with one that the user places in the same folder as the jar (or in a `./config` folder alongside it).

I have tried adding `.` to the classpath in the MANIFEST.MF, but that did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: How do you load the properties file?

Comment: The configs are loaded in the following line: `List<ResourceBundle> configs = Arrays.asList(new ResourceBundle[]{ResourceBundle.getBundle("oracle"), ResourceBundle.getBundle("dbinterface")});` I want to override only the dbinterface.properties file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement such a behaviour in the property file reading method. You could first try to read the property file at the location the user could create, and fallback to the original default one if not found. Something like:

```
FileInputStream propFile;
try {
    propFile = new FileInputStream(new File("dbinterface.properties"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    propFile = new FileInputStream(new File("resources/dbinterface.properties"));
}
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(propFile);
propFile.close();
```

Comment: This has crossed my mind, but if at all possible, I would like to avoid this. If I import the package with Maven and add a `dbinterface.properties` to my resources folder, it works, so I am wondering whether this is also possible after building a jar file out of my code.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to store user editable properties is the *users home dir*. In Java we have system independent access to the users home via `System.getProperty("user.home")`. This points to `/home/$USER` on linux and `%USERPROFILE%` on Windows. All other OS are also supported.

> You could first try to read the property file at the location the user could create, and fallback to the original default one if not found. - Galcoholic
>
> > I would like to avoid this. - padrino

Why?

This is the best possible approach:

- first read the properties file you delevered with you program,
- then (try to) read the settings your user changed from  `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),".myProgram/dbinterface.properties")`
  ( which is basically the other way arount as suggested by @Galcoholic)

When using the `Properties` class from the JVM to load them the settings will automatically be merged.